# Find NA cells by conditions and then assign values by other conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na

I have a `df` like this, I want to fill the `NA` by very complex conditions, but I don't know the coding..

```
df <- data.frame(
    age  = c("age15","age15","age16","age16"),
    occo = c("ag","ag","uuse","ag"),
    occn = c("tw","uuse","use","uuse"),
    num  = c(12,NA,567,NA),
    occo2 = c("ag","use","ag","use"),
    occn2 = c("tw","use","tw","use"), 
    num2  = c(2,45,67,789)
)
```

first, I want to find the `NA` cell in column `num` by condition `occo == "ag" & occn == "uuse"`, and then assign `num2` values with condition `occo2 == "ag" & occn2 == "tw"`, that is `2`.
more important, by `age` group, so the second `NA` would be replaced by `67`.

the expected result will be:

```
df <- data.frame(
    age  = c("age15","age15","age16","age16"),
    occo = c("ag","ag","uuse","ag"),
    occn = c("tw","uuse","use","uuse"),
    num  = c(12,2,567,67),
    occo2 = c("ag","use","ag","use"),
    occn2 = c("tw","use","tw","use"), 
    num2  = c(2,45,67,789)
)
```

something like this

```
df2 <- df %>%
 group_by(age) %>%
 mutate(num = case_when(
  occo == "ag" & occn == "uuse" ~ .[which(occo2 == "ag", occn2 == "tw"),][7]
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below creates the desired output, but is clearly not the intended way:

```
df |> 
mutate(num = if_else(is.na(num), lag(num2), num))
```

The assumption I have about the rules is:

For each age group, there's one num2 with occo2 == "ag" & occn2 == "tw", and one num which is NA, with occo == "ag" & occn == "uuse".

Set the value of the num value for each group to the num2 value that meets the above criteria, from the same group.

It's unclear though.

A longer example, one with more of the subtleties of the original dataset would be amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(num = if_else(occo == "ag" & occn == "uuse" & is.na(num), 
                       num2[occo2 == "ag" & occn2 == "tw"], num), .by = age)

#    age occo occn num occo2 occn2 num2
#1 age15   ag   tw  12    ag    tw    2
#2 age15   ag uuse   2   use   use   45
#3 age16 uuse  use 567    ag    tw   67
#4 age16   ag uuse  67   use   use  789
```

Basically what this says is if `occo == "ag" & occn == "uuse"` and `num` is `NA` then replace it with value in `num2` where `cco2 == "ag" & occn2 == "tw"` or else keep `num` as it is.

The `.by` syntax is available in `dplyr` 1.1.0 and above. If you have an older version of `dplyr` then you may add `group_by(age)` the same way that you have in your example.